# Changing the "Hover Over" colour in navigation menu items (EDITED)

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://www.new.techmoney360.com/ is the site I'm working on and it's all made in wordpress.

When you hover over the menu items in the nav bar, you'll notice they turn a darkish black, where instead of this I want to use a different colour.

I cannot seem to pinpoint where that bit of code is that's choosing the hover over colour, does anyone know where this is being set?

I've been digging through the theme files and I tried to use google's inspect element but I could not find it after all my searching. I'm not sure if it is a javascript that's doing this either.

EDIT ---------

To further help and find WHERE this color is being selected, I've opened up all files and tried to search anything related to "hover", and there isn't much...

Here is where I've been looking to try and find this, considering this is built in wordpress.

This is the navigation template file

```
<?php do_action('discussion_before_top_navigation'); ?>

<nav class="mkd-main-menu mkd-drop-down <?php echo esc_attr($additional_class); ?>">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-navigation' ,
    'container'  => '',
    'container_class' => '',
    'menu_class' => 'clearfix',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'fallback_cb' => 'top_navigation_fallback',
    'link_before' => '<span>',
    'link_after' => '</span>',
    'walker' => new DiscussionTopNavigationWalker()
)); ?>
</nav>

<?php do_action('discussion_after_top_navigation'); ?>
```

this is a css file that when I searched "hover" I found these:

```
h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover {
color: #fb4c35;
}

a,p a {
color: #121212;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-transition: color 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.7, 0.32, 0.9);
-moz-transition: color 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.7, 0.32, 0.9);
transition: color 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.7, 0.32, 0.9);
}

a:hover, p a:hover {
color: #fb4c35;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Either css using :hover or javascript ie .on(), .addEventLister(), etc

Comment: @j08691 that's my issue though? I'm not asking anyone to fix it I'm asking where should I look. 

I would LOVE to post code, because once I find that code I wouldnt have this issue. But hey, to make you happy, I'll post some code..

Comment: If it's a WP site it's either in your templates files, functions.php, or a plugin.

Comment: It is CSS, so you will be looking for a CSS/LESS/SASS file with the following selector: .mkd-main-menu.mkd-default-nav > ul > li > a{ color: black } you will want to ADD .mkd-main-menu.mkd-default-nav > ul > li > a:hover{color: NEWCOLOR}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set in /wp-content/themes/discussionwp/assets/css/modules.min.css?ver=4.3.4

```
.mkd-main-menu>ul>li.mkd-active-item>a, .mkd-main-menu>ul>li:hover>a {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id=ColoredMenuItem onmouseenter="ColoredMenuItem.bgcolor='lime'" onmouseleave="ColoredMenuItem.bgcolor=''"> hover over here </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```